# How to pass the value in html?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

when registering, the text that I store in html is sent to the mail, I want the values ​​of the user to be assigned to these values ​​and the text to be sent

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:remove="all">Template for HTML email</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <p th:text="${'Hello Dear,' + ${name}}">
    Hello Dear John Doe`</p>`


    <p th:text="${'Welcome.Please visit, http://aa.ru/activate-account/' + ${activationCode}}">
    Welcome. Please visit http://aa.ru/activate-account/%s
    </p>
<p>
      Thanks

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
        private TemplateEngine springTemplateEngine  = new TemplateEngine();
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("name",user.getUsername());
            context.setVariable("activationCode",user.getActivationCode());

        String text = springTemplateEngine.process("email-template.html",context);
        if (!org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) 
        {

            mailSenderService.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", text);
        }
```

here on mail should come message Hello Dear, Samir
Welcome.Please visit, http://aa.ru/activate-account/blabla

[image: cant find template]

[image]

```
templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("html/*"));
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the `email-template.html` located in? Is it directly inside the `templates` folder or is it in a sub-level? Also, have you tired removing the `.html` from your template's name? Normally you don't need that.

Comment: can you check please?

Comment: Yeah, you definetely don't need the `.html`.
`String text = springTemplateEngine.process("email-template",context);`

Comment: String text = springTemplateEngine().process("email-template", context);

Comment: it is dont solve problem

Comment: You issue is that you can't find your template right?

Comment: i cant find template, yes

Comment: Could you post the error you are receiving?

Comment: i post error which get from postman

Comment: I believe it has something to do with your template engine. I will give you an answer that I hope it works.

Comment: I just posted my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issues resides in this line.

```
private TemplateEngine springTemplateEngine  = new TemplateEngine();
```

It looks like you are creating a new template engine without any configuration. Normally, when I send emails in my projects, I use the template engine I configured in my MvcConfig class. So, first, let me show you my MvcConfig class.

**Config**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolverResolver() {
        final ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver =
                new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new UrlTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Now, whenever I send and email, I use the following lines. As you can see, I am fetching the template engine I configured on my MvcConfig class. Maybe, this could be the reason of your error.

```
MvcConfig config = new MvcConfig();
TemplateEngine templateEngine = config.templateEngine();
```

Comment: Which are? Also, this is an example, what I meant, is that you are creating a new TemplateEngine, when you should be used one that is already configured.

Comment: Also, there are a few things on my code that you don't need, like the `SpringSecurityDialect`.

Comment: what about final ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver =
                new ServletContextTemplateResolver();?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello Dear,laza</p>

<p>Welcome.Please visit <a href="http://aa.ru/activate-account/4255fdb0-bad2-48ee-84b0-ff404a549954" />
</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Now, that has to be with how you send it, which is a bit out of the scope of this question and which I believe should be in your `mailSenderService.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", text)` code.